# A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String' and The left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never executed

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I am getting 2 errors in my flutter project :

**A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'.**

and

**The left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never executed.
Try removing the operator and the right operand.**

My code where the error occur looks like this :

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
                    value: _currentSugars ?? userData.sugars, <-- and here **userData.sugars** (2)
                    decoration: textInputDecoration,
                    items: sugars.map((sugar) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: sugar,
                        child: Text('$sugar sugars'),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentSugars= val),  <-- in **val** (1)
                  ),
```

[Update 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpTbF.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the above code it seems that `_currentSugars` has a type `String`. Since `val` is actually of type `Object?` `_currentSugars= val` assignment cannot be performed.

Also, since a variable of type `String` cannot be `null` the compiler tells you that in an expression `_currentSugars ?? userData.sugars` the right side of it (`userData.sugars`) will never be executed.

You can try changing it to something like

```
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                value: _currentSugars ?? userData.sugars, 
                decoration: textInputDecoration,
                items: sugars.map((sugar) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: sugar,
                    child: Text('$sugar sugars'),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentSugars= val),
              ),
```

Additionally you need to change the type of `_currentSugars` from `String` to `String?`.

Comment: Can you change my code to see if it works or not?

Comment: You have added string but it still shows the same 2 red lines.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the new code, and show where you declare `_currentSugars`?

Comment: I am afraid you didn't change the type of the `_currentSugars` variable. And in your updated screenshot it is still impossible to see where it is actually declared.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235034/discussion-between-mike-osborn-and-saferif).